# How to compare dates in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, compare, date

I am setting up recent activities function where I get the all user activity from this week. However I don't know how to get all activity from this week as I need to compare the dates between now and a week before now. Please can you tell me how I can do this? I am using a MySQL database to hold all of the information. I have the tables, likes, follows, comments and posts. I would obviously need to compare dates to get all of the information from all of the tables.

I use this method when I insert dates into my MySQL db.

```
function uk_date() {
        $sign = "-"; 
        $h = "0"; 
        $dst = "true"; 
        if ($dst) {
            $daylight_saving = date('I');
            if ($daylight_saving){
               if ($sign == "-"){ $h=$h-1;  }
               else { $h=$h+1; }
          }
        }
        $hm = $h * 60;
        $ms = $hm * 60;
        if ($sign == "-"){ $timestamp = time()-($ms); }
        else { $timestamp = time()+($ms); }
        return $gmdate = gmdate("d/m/Y g:i:s A", $timestamp);
    }
```

Also, the field "date" in my db is not a timestamp, it is a string generated from the uk_date() method above. This is where I am unsure of how to compare the dates.

Comment: Have you looked at strtotime function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from table where datetime_field > now() - interval 7 day
```

Comment: The field isn't a timestamp, its a string generated by the uk_date() method.

Comment: But the suggestions is - this SHOULDN'T be any "generated" date. Store in DB as plain data as you can, and if talking about dates, the plainest thing is always a unix timestamp, as it is nativelly handled by most APIs in the world... (ok, I know we can discuss that fact, but that's not the point)

Comment: @ XcodeDev; Yes, but it seems to me that he does things too complicated.

Comment: I admit that I do. So how can I compare the date strings that have been generated?

Answer (score 1):

Don't exactly understand, why this need to be so complicated, why to work with daylight_saving etc...

Is it possible, that you simply store to database the result of call to time() ? Then you'll have unix-timestamp, and that is easily comparable with any other desired unix timestamp. All arithmetic is trivial then... am I right ?

Comment: +1 For using UNIX instead GMT in database. Its lighter(in performance), also its easier to use.

Comment: Sorry, I can't agree with that. Storing any "d/m/Y g:i:s A" is a prey for a trouble. Really, this gives you no pros, and many cons - but of course that's my personal opinion. DONT store any "generated" dates.

Comment: Ok, I have already stored them though. Please can you tell me how I can compare the generated dates?

Comment: Please understand that your question arised only because the date is badly stored... So why not converting all dates to timestamps at once using some simple converting script, and stop that "conversion madness" from escalating in the future ?